# Can I use dtype to find the elements of an numpy array are strings?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I got an numpy array, for example:

```
myArray = np.array(['a','bc'])
```

Is it possible use `dtype` to find out, whether its elements are strings？

The only way I can do is checking `myArray.dtype == 'S2'`, but my Problem is I don't know in advance how many character are there in my elements.

Can I use something like `myArray.dtype == 'str'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`issubdtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html) to do the checking:

```
>>> np.issubdtype(myArray.dtype, str)
True
```

The function checks whether a given dtype is ordered below another in NumPy's [type hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html).

Alternatively, you could inspect the dtype's character code directly. String types have code `'S'`:

```
>>> myArray.dtype.char
'S'
```

Comment: +1 Wasn't aware of `np.issubdtype`, I was usually check this stuff as `issubclass(myArray.dtype.type, str)`.